# Using React Higher Order Component - Specifcally react-sortable-hoc

Tags: list, reactjs, drag-and-drop, npm, higher-order-functions

I am having trouble understanding a very basic part of this HOC that has a good traction on NPM so I am guessing there is an easy answer here:

Where do my pre-existing components go in the example he gives on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable-hoc).  Is `{value}` supposed to be replaced with `<myComponent />`?  I know these wrappers are supposed to take my component, in this case components, as arguments, but I think I am missing something integral here.  Any help appreciated.  His example documentation is below

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-list-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li>{value}</li>);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((value, index) =>
                <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
});

class SortableComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']
    }
    onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
        this.setState({
            items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex)
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />
        )
    }
}

render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Did you try by replacing <li>{value}</li> by <myComponent value={value}/> ?

Comment: The hang up I am having has to do with my substitution for {items} on SortableContainer()  Right now I am attempting to do this :

Comment: const SortableList = SortableContainer((CampaignLabels) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {CampaignLabels.map((value, index) =>
                <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
});

Comment: And it's not working saying I cannot map CampaignLabels

Comment: First , you should have written `({CampaignLabels})`, not `(CampaignLabels)`. Read [destructuring](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread/blob/master/Rest.md#object-rest-destructuring). Then, `CampaignLabels` must be passed as props through `SortableList `. So you should have something like: `<SortableList CampaignLabels=[]/>`. Hope that help :)

Answer (score 1):

`SortableElement` will wrap your component to benefit from `react-sortable-hoc` features. So you have to write something like that (Assuming `<myComponent />` is an element of the list):

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(myComponent);
```

This will create a list element that will render `myComponent` with additional features.

`({value}) => <li>{value}</li>` is a stateless function representing a React Component. You could have write:

```
const myComponent = ({value}) => <li>{value}</li>;
const SortableItem = SortableElement(myComponent);
```